# Save a file as .h5 properly

Tags: python, pandas, h5py

I have some .h5 files which I read using `pd.read_hdf("input.h5")`, I turn them to numpy arrays, process them and then I want to save them again as .h5 file. I found that the way to do it is like this:

```
hf = h5py.File('output.h5', 'w')
hf.create_dataset('dataset_1', data=numpy_data)
hf.close()
```

But when I try `pd.read_hdf("output.h5")` I get this: `ValueError: No dataset in HDF5 file.` It seems that I can read it using `h5py.File('output.h5', 'r').get('dataset_1')`, however I need to use `pd.read_hdf("output.h5")`, as this is integrated in a bigger code. How can I save the .h5 such that to be able to read it the way I want? Thank you!

Comment: Double check the `pandas` option.  I believe it uses `pytables` rather than `h5py`.

Comment: Use pandas to save those arrays, if you want to read them with pandas as well.